# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loads property files during startup?

Tags: spring, properties

Anyone know, if Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loads property files during app startup?
If so, does it do by default or we have to set some kind of parameter to make sure it loads during app startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is a bean factory postprocessor. A bean post processor works with the bean factory before any bean has bean instantiated (other than other bean factory postprocessors).It alters the bean factory.

Therefore it always runs at application startup to resolve property values delimited with ${}. It will never execute again in the lifecycle of the Spring application.